# Apple Music (MusicKit) userToken outside iOS

Tags: python, api, itunes, apple-music, apple-musickit

I'm trying to develop an app that can interact with the user music library. The application will be Windows-based (so far). I had no problem with Spotify and other music APIs. However, I'm stuck with Apple Music (MusicKit) API.

I was able to create the developer Token and everything, but apparently, if I'm gonna interact with the user library, I need his authorization (obviously). However, Apple Music documentation is pretty vague (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applemusicapi/getting_keys_and_creating_tokens).

There is a function to requestUserToken, but apparently it is only for iOS/Android/JS apps.

Is there any way to get a user token o to create one? My interest to be able to add, remove, edit user tracks in the Apple Music library (iTunes actually, but for Apple Music libraries).

I'm developing this in Python because there where many Python API libraries and was very easy to setup.

If it's not possible, then I should switch to another environment, but all the work so far will be lost basically.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds interesting, which other music APIs and is your code available (github, ...). You might want to have a look at [python-social-auth](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/apple.html) there is an 'Apple Backend'.

Comment: Haven't created a GitHub yet, so far is a personal project! I found Spotify, Napster, Google Play, Youtube Music, Deezer and Tidal APIs for Python, or at least easy to implement!